# How to Call method with arguments coming from a hashset?

Tags: java, android, collections, hashset

```
  static public void Configure( Activity activity,String client_options,
        String app_id, String... zone_ids )
```

I have this hashset that contains up to 500 elements.

How can I call Configure() with each element of the hashset as a argument fulfilling the zone_ids parameter?

Comment: Side-note: I suggest you change your names to follow Java conventions: `configure` as the method name, and `clientOptions`, `appId` and `zoneIds` for the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you'd need to convert the set to an array - it's easy to do, but quite inefficient:

```
Configure(activity, options, appId, zoneIdSet.toArray(new String[0]));
```

The `new String[0]` could be replaced by `new String[zoneIdSet.size()]` to be slightly more efficient. You have to pass in an array to get around the type erasure of Java, so that it can build an array of the correct type.

You've said you have no control over the method - if you *could*, it would be cleaner to have two overloads:

```
public void configure(Activity activity, String clientOptions,
    String appId, Iterable<String> zoneIds) {
    // Actual work here
}

// Convenience overload
public void configure(Activity activity, String clientOptions,
    String appId, Iterable<String> zoneIds) {
    configure(activity, clientOptions, appId, Lists.asList(zoneIds));
}
```

Then you'd just "wrap" the array in a list to make it an `Iterable<String>`.

Comment: I have no control over the method though.

Comment: @sirvon: Where did I suggest changing the method?

Comment: thanks for that extra note, i guess i wish i had control. But this is perfect.

Comment: would it be even more efficent to just put the 500 strings into an array first and bypass the set?

Comment: @sirvon not if the `Set` is being used to guarantee uniqueness.